# Lua os.date() function not working in Computer Craft

Tags: date, lua, minecraft, computercraft

I'm trying to make an analog clock display the time (12-hour) and I have to use Lua. I use the following line to get the time in this format:

```
os.date('%I:%M')
```

This apparently doesn't work as I keep getting a nil error, this is the only thing wrong with the code. os.time works fine but not os.date; I even tried without the '%I:%M' (The format for the time) and it still doesn't work with os.date().

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to import the date function from some other library? I am a total Lua nooby BTW...

I'm actually using it to work monitors for ComputerCraft on Minecraft but the code is:

```
m = peripheral.wrap('back')
m.setTextScale(5)
while i == i do
m.clear()
m.setCursorPos(1,1)
x = os.date('%I:%M')
m.write(x)
sleep(60)
end
```

The thing is though that the rest of the code doesn't affect it. The os.date is the only problem because I try it seperately and it gives me the same error "attempt to call nil".

Comment: I think you need to show a bit more of your *actual* code... What you've posted looks fine, but doesn't make sense on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://computercraft.info/wiki/index.php?title=OS_%28API%29), ComputerCraft doesn't appear to expose `os.date()`.  A workaround is suggested [here](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/1401-two-questions-here/):

> Unfortunately the date and time are not exposed to us. In Lua, the os.date() and os.time() functions would be what we want, however in ComputerCraft date is not implemented and time gives the minecraft time.
>
> The only way I know of to get the real date and time is to get it from the web using the http API.

Answer (score 1):

also, if you want the minecraft date, try using `os.getday()`